# Protractor - getting the text out of getText()

Tags: protractor, angular-promise

I'm trying to figure out how to get the actual text values of a getText() in the following scenario:

```
var elementNameRow = element.all(by.name('nameRow')).count().then(function(size){
  thisNum = parseInt(Math.random() * (size - 0) + 0);

  thisLast = element.all(by.name('last')).get(thisNum).getText();
  thisFirst = element.all(by.name('first')).get(thisNum).getText();

  console.log(thisLast.resolve());

  var elementNameRowSelect = element.all(by.name('nameRow')).get(thisNum).click();
  var newElement = element(by.tagName('h3'));
  var expectedString = thisFirst + " " + thisLast;
  expect(newElement.getText()).toContain(expectedString);
});
```

As you probably deduced, `expectedString` equals a couple `[Object Object]` pieces.

How can I get the text of those names to use in the expect? I've watched the test go through and everything else works as expected. It does the right thing, clicks the right links, etc. I can tell from the error messages that it even got the right thing in `newElement`. It just doesn't realize that since I can't get the proper text to compare against. I've seen a couple similar questions on here, but I can't quite figure out how to apply those answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1:  use async / await

You should use async / await when possible. You will need to set the flag `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` to false to disable the default control flow:

it('some description', async() => {
    let elementNameRow = await element.all(by.name('nameRow')).count().then((size) => {
      thisNum = parseInt(Math.random() * (size - 0) + 0);

```
  thisLast = await element.all(by.name('last')).get(thisNum).getText();
  thisFirst = await element.all(by.name('first')).get(thisNum).getText();

  console.log(thisLast + ' ' + thisFirst);

  await element.all(by.name('nameRow')).get(thisNum).click();
  let newElement = element(by.tagName('h3'));
  expect(await newElement.getText()).toContain(thisLast + ' ' + thisFirst);
});
```

});

### Option 2: nested promises

I usually tell people to nest your promises in then blocks to resolve the `getText` OR you could put them on a promise array and do a promise.all then.

Without promise.all

```
  it('some description',() => {
    let elementNameRow = element.all(by.name('nameRow')).count().then((size) => {
      thisNum = parseInt(Math.random() * (size - 0) + 0);

      element.all(by.name('last')).get(thisNum).getText().then(thisLast => {
        return element.all(by.name('first')).get(thisNum).getText().then(thisFirst => {
          return element.all(by.name('nameRow')).get(thisNum).click().then(() => {
            let newElement = element(by.tagName('h3'));
            expect(newElement.getText()).toContain(thisLast + ' ' + thisFirst);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

If you use Promise.all:

```
  it('some description',() => {
    let elementNameRow = element.all(by.name('nameRow')).count().then((size) => {
      thisNum = parseInt(Math.random() * (size - 0) + 0);
      let promises = [];
      let thisFirst = '';
      let thisLast = '';
      promises.push(element.all(by.name('last')).get(thisNum).getText()
          .then(text => { thisLast = text; });
      promises.push(element.all(by.name('first')).get(thisNum).getText()
          .then(text => { thisFirst = text; });
      promises.push(element.all(by.name('nameRow')).get(thisNum).click());
      Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        // resolve the get text and click on the name row
        let newElement = ;
        expect(element(by.tagName('h3')).getText()).toContain(thisLast + ' ' + thisFirst);
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: I ended up doing the nesting approach. Now I feel a bit better knowing that it was one of your suggestions! LOL!